# Configure an Android Studio (or IntelliJ IDEA) plugin manually

Tags: plugins, android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use a [plugin](https://github.com/phrase/Phrase-AndroidStudio) in Android Studio, but, there is an [Android Studio bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=171090) that prevents me from launching File->Other Settings->Configure Plugins.

Its a simple plugin, open source, its requesting a parameter named "name" that I'd like to configure manually somehow, perhaps in the file system?

Problem line: https://github.com/phrase/Phrase-AndroidStudio/blob/master/src/com/phraseapp/androidstudio/TokenRepository.java#L19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File | Other Settings | Configure Plugins runs the wizard that can enable or disable certain plugins. It does not allow you to change the settings of a plugin.

To change the settings of a plugin, use the regular Settings dialog.